# How to get output from hashtable into CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Trying to create a script that will go to a remote (Windows 7) virtual machine, and get the printers (name, driver, and IP address) and output them to a file.

I can get it to display in the console but I need an output file. Going through a migration from Windows 7 to 10 and trying to avoid having to go to the old virtual to copy information. Because Windows 7 is involved, we can't use the `Get-Printer` cmdlet.

I've been able to hack together this little bit of code but no matter what I've tried, am unable to get it to go elsewhere in a readable format.

```
Write-Host "Getting Printer info from old VM"
$hostAddresses = @{}

Get-WmiObject Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -ComputerName $oldvm | ForEach-Object {
    $hostAddresses.Add($_.Name, $_.HostAddress)
}

Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $oldvm | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "DriverName" = $_.DriverName
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "HostAddress" = $hostAddresses[$_.PortName]
    }
}
```

Comment: `Get-WmiObject ... | ForEach-Object {...} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType`

Answer (score 0):

After your last bracket pipe it to export-csv:

```
| Export-Csv -Path C:\PATH\TO\CSV.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

I use a semicolon as delimeter in this case, you can use whatever obviously :)